# Is every `.class` file generated by `scalac` also obtainable via `javac`?

Tags: java, scala, compilation, bytecode

Is it true that for every `.class` file that was created by the Scala compiler `scalac`, it is theoretically possible to define a `.java` file that gets compiled, by `javac`, to exactly this same `.class` file?

If not, can you give one or more non-trivial examples of constructions in Scala that get compiled to JVM bytecode for which there is no corresponding Java construction?

Comment: I'm going to answer "no" to *both* of those questions.

Comment: Kayaman is right, how about you trying to, for example, create java code that becomes identical to scala's Hello World after compilation?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it true that for every `.class` file that was created by the Scala compiler `scalac`, it is theoretically possible to define a `.java` file that gets compiled, by `javac`, to exactly this same `.class` file?

No.

> If not, can you give one or more examples of constructions in Scala that get compiled to JVM bytecode for which there is no corresponding Java construction?

```scala
class `class`
```

`class` is a legal name for a class in Scala, but not in Java, so it is impossible to get the Java compiler to generate a bytecode file with a class named `class`.

Comment: Here I'm creating class `class` in Java: `import javassist.ClassPool;` `import javassist.CtClass;` `public class App { public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault(); CtClass ctClass = pool.makeClass("class"); Class<?> clazz = ctClass.toClass(); ClassLoader classLoader = clazz.getClassLoader(); Class.forName("class", true, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()); } }`

Comment: Does that really generate the same bytecode as my Scala example? I highly doubt that.

Comment: Maybe I misread OP's question. I was thinking about generation of bytecode from Java at runtime. And OP probably asked about bytecode generated from this Java source upon compilation.

Comment: What if I do similar thing at compile time i.e. generate bytecode with some bytecode-generating library called inside a macro in Scala or inside compile-time annotation processing in Java. Will it count as one of results of compilation? :)

Comment: @DmytroMitin the question clearly refers to *javac* as bytecode generator

Comment: Thanks for that example. I was looking for more non-trivial ones, though. Also, a class file generated by `scalac` includes the description `Compiled from [...].scala`, while a class file generated by `javac` includes the description `Compiled from [...].java`.

Comment: @DanielGerigk the “Compiled from” phrase is not part of the description in the class file. There’s [an optional attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.10) containing the name of a source file. When you compile with `javac` and use `-g:none` to compile without debug attributes, it will not be present. I suppose, `scalac` has a similar option. Further, you could alter the attribute without affecting semantics. So this is not a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

- Scala being compiled inserts ScalaSig (scala signatures) into bytecode, i.e. Scala-specific kind of comments. These "comments" will be absent in class files compiled from Java sources.
- Java being compiled can generate annotations (`@`) visible with Java reflection at runtime while Scala can't. Scala can only generate annotations visible at sources and class files but not at runtime with Java reflection although they can be visible at runtime with Scala reflection (because some info is written to ScalaSigs).